# Highest occupant with his details using view & max?

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, datediff, sql-view

**Query to get the house details of the house having the highest occupancy**
There are two tables **houses & tenant histories** used to calculate the highest occupancy.
So first I'm using **datediff** function to get the duration of stay.
then I create view so that it act as a virtual table & I can access the column to get max value.

```
create view [dbo].[vWHouseStay]
as
    select profile_id, 
    house_Id, 
    house_type,
    bhk_details,Bed_type,
    bed_count,
    furnishing_type ,
    DATEDIFF(MONTH,move_in_date,move_out_date) AS 'Total Length of stay'
from Tenancy_histories
join houses on  tenancy_histories.house_Id = houses.house_id
```

What I need is highest occupant with house details. How do I do that? Basically it should just return one house with max [Total Length of stay].

table structure:

```
**Tenancy_histories**
Field Type Null Key Default
id int(11) NO PRI auto_increment
profile_id int(11) NO FK
house_id int(11) NO FK
move_in_date date NO
move_out_date date YES
rent int(11) NO
Bed_type varchar(255) YES
move_out_reason varchar(255) YES

**Houses**
Field Type Null Key Default
house_id int(11) NO PRI auto_increment
house_type varchar(255) YES
bhk_details varchar(255) YES
bed_count int(11) NO
furnishing_type varchar(255) YES
Beds_vacant int(11) NO
```

**sample data**

```
 house_id   house_type  bhk_details bed_count   furnishing_type OccupancyDays
5   Independent 4 BHK   4   fully-furnished 443
7   Apartment   3 BHK   3   semifurnished   417
4   Apartment   2 BHK   2   fully-furnished 397
18  Independent 2 BHK   2   fully-furnished 358
16  Apartment   3 BHK   3   fully-furnished 324
19  Independent 3 BHK   3   fully-furnished 290
3   Apartment   3 BHK   6   fully-furnished 226
1   Apartment   3 BHK   5   unfurnished NULL
2   Apartment   3 BHK   3   unfurnished NULL
17  Independent 3 BHK   3   fully-furnished NULL
6   Apartment   3 BHK   3   semifurnished   NULL
8   Apartment   2 BHK   4   fully-furnished NULL
```

**sample data [tenancy histories]**

```
    id  profile_id  house_id    move_in_date    move_out_date   rent    Bed_type    move_out_reason
242 1   5   2015-02-12  2016-04-30  7500    bed MOVE_OUT
243 2   2   2015-06-05  NULL    11000   room    
244 3   4   2015-10-28  2016-11-28  12000   room    RENT_CHANGE
245 4   1   2015-04-26  NULL    8000    bed 
246 5   3   2015-05-15  2015-12-27  9000    bed MOVE_OUT
247 6   8   2015-12-25  NULL    10200   room    
248 7   6   2015-11-20  NULL    6500    bed 
249 8   7   2015-11-10  2016-12-31  7200    bed MOVE_OUT
250 9   9   2015-10-15  NULL    7500    bed 
251 10  10  2015-06-20  NULL    7500    bed 
252 11  19  2015-08-29  2016-06-14  8000    bed INTERNAL_TRANSFER
253 12  15  2015-02-24  NULL    11000   room    
254 13  12  2015-02-25  NULL    12000   room    
255 14  18  2016-01-07  2016-12-30  13500   room    MOVE_OUT
256 15  13  2015-04-07  NULL    6500    bed 
257 16  17  2015-04-23  NULL    6500    bed 
258 17  14  2015-02-10  NULL    10500   room    
259 18  16  2015-10-16  2016-09-04  8000    bed MOVE_OUT
260 19  20  2015-09-26  NULL    7500    bed 
261 20  11  2015-09-30  NULL    9500    bed
```

Comment: Please give us your required output column names

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: `select top 1 <your query> order by DATEDIFF(MONTH,move_in_date,move_out_date) desc`? Note this isn't sargable so an index on these data columns would be ignored and could hurt your performance.

Comment: Where's your table structure???  How do you expect us to help you without table structures????

Comment: @scsimon : hey it worked . thanks . Also , am i going the right way  using datediff function to calculate highest occupancy . I have mentioned the tables with which i have to work

Comment: Sure thing @chahakjoshi  and yes although I’d use DAY instead of MONTH for more granular results, at least in the ORDER BY

Comment: hey @scsimon, i think this order by code is more apt if i have to calculate who stayed the longest  rather than which house has been occupied the most??

Comment: correct, that is what it's calculating currently. I see your issue now, and will post an answer

Comment: Do you always want exactly one house returned even if there are multiple tenancies that are tied for being the longest? If so, does it matter which of those multiple houses is returned?

Comment: @JoeFarrell : hey :) , i need to find out which house has been occupied the most and it's ok if there are mutliple tenancies for the house that has been occupied maximum number of times.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to aggregate over all tenancy history. Here would be how. This can be used in a view as well.

```
;with cte as(
select
    h.house_id
    ,h.house_type
    ,h.bhk_details
    ,h.bed_count
    ,h.furninshing_type
    ,OccupancyDays = sum(datediff(day,th.move_in_date,move_out_date))
from 
    Houses h
inner join
    Tenancy_histories th on th.house_id = h.house_id)
group by
    h.house_id
    ,h.house_type
    ,h.bhk_details
    ,h.bed_count
    ,h.furninshing_type

select TOP 1 --you can remove the TOP 1 to bring them all back 
*
from cte
order by OccupancyDays desc
```

Comment: hey, i tried that but it gave an error."Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Column 'Houses.house_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: that was my fault @chahakjoshi i edited the answer. I assume here that house_id is unique in the house table based on the auto-increment

Comment: It worked but output similar to " select top 1 <your query> order by DATEDIFF(MONTH,move_in_date,move_out_date) desc" ... which was giving the longest the person has stayed. so, I'm a bit confused the logic for highest occupancy of a house & longest duration of stay will be the same?

Comment: This new approach looks at the days of ALL occupants for a given house instead of showing rows for each occupant. In the first one, you should have seen multiple rows for each house which had multiple occupants. If each house only had a single occupant, then the results would be the same. Sample data from you would help to show this, and explain

Comment: @ scsimon if you could explain the approach that would really help me out.  I have added sample data in my ques. like you asked.

Comment: can you add some sample data for Tenancy_histories too? Or would this be the result of your join?

Comment: previous data was result of join.i have also provided tenancy_histories sample data